# issues with this program

Tags: javascript, function

I came across this program from a [You Don't Know JS books](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch1.md) book on github:

```
const SPENDING_THRESHOLD = 200;
const TAX_RATE = 0.08;
const PHONE_PRICE = 99.99;
const ACCESSORY_PRICE = 9.99;

var bank_balance = 303.91;
var amount = 0;

function calculateTax(amount) {
    return amount * TAX_RATE;
}

function formatAmount(amount) {
    return "$" + amount.toFixed( 2 );
}

// keep buying phones while you still have money
while (amount < bank_balance) {
    // buy a new phone!
    amount = amount + PHONE_PRICE;

    // can we afford the accessory?
    if (amount < SPENDING_THRESHOLD) {
        amount = amount + ACCESSORY_PRICE;
    }
}

// don't forget to pay the government, too
amount = amount + calculateTax( amount );

console.log(
    "Your purchase: " + formatAmount( amount )
);
// Your purchase: $334.76

// can you actually afford this purchase?
if (amount > bank_balance) {
    console.log(
        "You can't afford this purchase. :("
    );
}
// You can't afford this purchase. :(
```

My issue is that it does not matter if I change the value of `bank_balance` to a higher value, but it keeps printing : `You can't afford this purchase.`

I have try to make it so it does not print : `You can't afford this purchase.`

I can't make it work. I'm starting to think that the program is wrong, but I think is just me.

I know the solution is simple but I cant see it nor find it.

Comment: Add some `console.log`s here and there to see what's going on.

Comment: Did you consider the taxes (which are ignored when choosing how many phones are bought)?

Comment: If may have to do with the "keep buying phones while you still have money" comment :-?

Comment: To be honest, the program is a bit stupid - it keeps incrementing the amount spent until it gets close to the threshold and then adds tax which takes it over. get a better book!

Comment: @Jamiec I know but its the one the most people recommended :/ plus its free

Comment: Try and make your titles more descriptive of the actual issue

Answer (score 2):

It comes from your `while(amount < bank_balance)`. You increase `amount` until it's bigger than `bank_balance`. So obviously, it's bigger than `bank_balance` after that.

Also, you can use the developer tools available in every modern browser (F12 for Chrome or Firefox will open them), where you can put break points and follow your code's flow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the program is *meant* to do but it doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

It "buys" phones as long as you have money, but doesn't check if you have enough money for an additional phone.
So in the end of the `while` loop you have spend exactly your whole money on phones or (much more likely) spend more money than you have.

On top of this there are accessorizes and taxes. So in the end, you won't ever be able to afford your purchase.

And no matter how high you raise you balance, the program is written to exceed it.

The programm would work probably better with the line

```py
while (amount + PHONE_PRICE + calculateTax(amount + PHONE_PRICE) <= bank_balance)
```

or even

```py
while (amount + PHONE_PRICE + ACCESSORY_PRICE + calculateTax(amount + PHONE_PRICE + ACCESSORY_PRICE)<= bank_balance)
```

Although I have to admit that I'm not sure what the purpose of the `SPENDING_THRESHOLD` is.

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding new phones and accessories until it reaches the total amount. I guess total cost becomes very close to the amount hence when you add the tax on top of that it crosses the limit and you see that message. I would suggest you to compare(in the while loop) the phone price along with the tax. Something like:

```
while (amount + PHONE_PRICE + calculateTax( PHONE_PRICE ) < bank_balance) {
    // buy a new phone!
    amount = amount + PHONE_PRICE + calculateTax( PHONE_PRICE );

    // can we afford the accessory?
    if (amount < SPENDING_THRESHOLD) {
        amount = amount + ACCESSORY_PRICE;
    }
}
```

Refer https://jsfiddle.net/Lxwscbbq/
Open the browser console to see the messages.

Comment: No taxes on accessories?

Answer (score 0):

Program is not wrong it is simple:

```
var bank_balance = 303.91;
```

which is global. Suppose you provided

```
amount = 200;
amount = amount + calculateTax( amount );
amount = 200 + calculateTax(200);
```

if you check condition and you can see amount is grater than entered amount. Thats why you are getting "You can't afford purchase"

```
if (amount > bank_balance) {
    console.log(
        "You can't afford this purchase. :("
    );
}
```

Comment: It even starts before that. He buy the first phone for 99.99, then accessories for 9.99. Since `amount now equals 109.98, he buys another phone for 99.99 (amount = 209.97) and no accessories. Since he still has money he buys a third phone for 99.99 and amount reaches 309.96 (before taxes) which already is more then the 303.91 he has.

Comment: Check you while loop where you have been buying product until **balance** money is greater than **amount**

and then check **if** condition between while loop it also increase value of your amount and after you have increased value of **amount** outside the loop also. this is the case of your wrong output